# Java calling value from a method

Tags: java, class, methods

first of all sorry for my english it is not perfect.
I got a little problem (for me a huge problem) in java.

```
package test;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class adress {

    String adress;
    String city;
    int postcode;
    String ergebnis;



    public void setadress(String adress)
    {
        this.adress = adress;
    }

    public String getadress()
    {
        return adress;
    }


    public void setcity(String city)
    {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getcity()
    {
        return city;
    }

    public void setpostcode(int postcode)
    {
        this.postcode = postcode;
    }

    public int getpostcode()
    {
        return postcode;
    }

    public void output (String adress, String city, int postcode) {

        Scanner a = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("How much values?");
        int b = a.nextInt();
        int [] c  = new int [b];

        for (int i=0; i<c.length; i++)  {



            Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
            System.out.println("Adress?");
            String temp = input.nextLine();
            setadresse(temp);

            Scanner input3 = new Scanner (System.in);
            System.out.println("City?");
            String temp2 = input3.nextLine();
            setcity(temp2);

            Scanner input4 = new Scanner (System.in);
            System.out.println("Postcode?");
            int temp3 = input4.nextInt();
            setpostcode(temp3);

            this.adress = adress;
            this.city = city;
            this.postcode = postcode;


            System.out.println("Adress: "+adress+"City"+city+"postcode"+postcode);

        }


    }

}
```

Now, i want to save the values in a new class in a array

```
package test;

public class save {

    adress [] saver = new adress[10];

    public adressenpool (String adress, String city, int postcode){



        for(int i =0; i<10;i++)
            saver[i] = ????? ;   //i have tried several things here, but it will not work. i know it is      just a little problem but i can't get it the mistake

    }


}

}
```

How can i get the values from address class an copy it as an array in the saver class?

Comment: Instantiate an object of your address class in saver class. And get them via getter or something. Or instantiate an object of your save class in the address class and write the values to the array via your addresspool method.

Comment: What you have currently appears to be attempting to put 10 objects of class Address in an object of class save, as opposed to just the information *within* address

Comment: Btw minor point. Classes always start with an uppercase letter. Objects with lowercase. So it should be class `Save` and class `Address`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are attempting to put 10 objects of class address in an object of class save, as opposed to just the information within address. This is generally a good idea so I encourage you to continue.

In order to create the address within method adressenpool you need to use its constructor. At present class `address` only had a default constructor, which creates an effectively empty address. I would add a new constructor that fully creates the object

```
public class adress {

     String adress;
     String city;
     int postcode;
     String ergebnis;

     public adress(String adress, String city, int postcode, String ergebnis){
          this.adress=address;
          this.city=city;
          this.postcode=postcode;
          this.ergebnis=ergebnis;

     }

     //you can have several constructors so you can keep the empty constructor if you want to set the elements piece by piece
     public adress(){
     }

     ......
     other methods as before
}
```

Having added the constructor you can now make addresses easily

```
  public adressenpool (String adress, String city, int postcode,String ergebnis){

        saver[0] = new adress(adress, city, postcode,ergebnis);
  }
```

However, your method adressenpool only contains enough information to create 1 adress. You may wish to set which index to save it at. Or you may want to change from an array to an arraylist so you can just add new `adress` as you go.

```
  public adressenpool (String adress, String city, int postcode,String ergebnis, int index){

        saver[index] = new adress(adress, city, postcode,ergebnis);
  }
```

## Notes

- Classes always start with an uppercase letter. Objects with
  lowercase. So it should be class `Save` and class `Address`
- For loops (and if statements) without braces are considered a dangerous thing to do. Always include `{}` with your loops even if it contains a single statement. So

  ```
   for(int i =0; i<10;i++){
      saver[i] new Adress(adress, city, postcode,ergebnis);
   }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be more specific of what you want to do exactly.
Your first class has 4 members (3 `String` and 1 `int`) and you want to save the *values from address class as an array in the saver class*? What do you mean by the last one?

I am guessing you need to fill each address instance in the array you define (`saver`) by calling the appropriate setters. (You haven't defined `setadresse()` by the way). This can be done in a loop for example.

Also this is not very straight forward: `//i have tried several things here, but it will not work.` What have you tried and did not work?

Of course you need a `main()` function also to run your program.

I hope that helped a bit...

Answer (score 0):

This will solve the issue

```
package temp;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class adress {

     String adress;
     String city;
     int postcode;
     String ergebnis;



   public void setadress(String adress) 
    {
        this.adress = adress;
    }

    public String getadress() 
    {
        return adress;
    }


     public void setcity(String city) 
    {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getcity() 
    {
        return city;
    }

    public void setpostcode(int postcode) 
    {
        this.postcode = postcode;
    }

    public int getpostcode() 
    {
        return postcode;
    }

    public void setAddress () {


        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Adress?");
        String temp = input.nextLine();
        setadress(temp);

        Scanner input3 = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("City?");
        String temp2 = input3.nextLine();
        setcity(temp2);

        Scanner input4 = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Postcode?");
        int temp3 = input4.nextInt();
        setpostcode(temp3);



    }



    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return "Adress: "+adress+"City"+city+"postcode"+postcode;
    }



}
```

And the second class

```
package temp;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class save {

    adress [] saver;


    public save(){
        saver = new adress[10];
    }

    public void adressenpool(){
        Scanner a = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("How much values?");
        int b = a.nextInt();
        adress address1 = null;
        for (int i=0; i<b; i++)  {    

            address1 = new adress();
            address1.setAddress();


            this.saver[i] = address1;
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        save saveTemp = new save();
        saveTemp.adressenpool();
        for(int i=0; i<2; i++){

            System.out.println(saveTemp.saver[i].toString());
        }
    }

}
```